# Pyautogui For Loop Skips

Tags: python, pyautogui

i'm having an issue looping through a list of items and using the pyautogui.write function to input in items from each iterated items in a text box,basically what happens is that the loop skips sometimes two items or three items, here is my code
The name_list argument here is an actual list of names

```
def send_name(name_list):
    time.sleep(4)
    pyautogui.click(1024,227)
    for name in name_list:
        create_request = pyautogui.click(1195,239)
        time.sleep(1)
        acct = pyautogui.click(1018,392)
        pyautogui.click(1053,427)
        promo_code_box = pyautogui.click(1006,466)
        pyautogui.write(name)
        time.sleep(2) 
        pyautogui.doubleClick(880,436)    
        quantity = pyautogui.click(998,533)
        submit = pyautogui.click(754,577)
        time.sleep(1)
        confirm = pyautogui.click(757,487)
        pyautogui.click(778,245)
```

for instance if the name_list was ['prada','gucci','adidas','nike','puma','dior'] - the loop will skip like 2 items in here whereas i'll need it to loop through all the list
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding more sleep statements should ensure no skipping:

```
def send_name(name_list):
    time.sleep(4)
    pyautogui.click(1024,227)
    for name in name_list:
        time.sleep(1)
        create_request = pyautogui.click(1195,239)
        time.sleep(1)
        acct = pyautogui.click(1018,392)
        time.sleep(1)
        pyautogui.click(1053,427)
        time.sleep(1)
        promo_code_box = pyautogui.click(1006,466)
        time.sleep(1)
        pyautogui.write(name)
        time.sleep(2) 
        pyautogui.doubleClick(880,436)
        time.sleep(1)
        quantity = pyautogui.click(998,533)
        time.sleep(1)
        submit = pyautogui.click(754,577)
        time.sleep(1)
        confirm = pyautogui.click(757,487)
        time.sleep(1)
        pyautogui.click(778,245)
```

Comment: thank you for your help, it appears to be working this time except now it skips the first item

Comment: see the extra sleep

Comment: how about adding a sleep under `pyautogui.click(1024,227)`

Comment: hi i tried it again, it is still not working, i'm going to try using the reversed keyword to loop it from the end

Answer (score 0):

U can use

```
pyautogui.PAUSE = 1 `(or more)`

def send_name(name_list):
    time.sleep(4)
    pyautogui.click(1024,227)
    for name in name_list:
        create_request = pyautogui.click(1195,239)
        time.sleep(1)
        acct = pyautogui.click(1018,392)
        pyautogui.click(1053,427)
        promo_code_box = pyautogui.click(1006,466)
        pyautogui.write(name)
        time.sleep(2) 
        pyautogui.doubleClick(880,436)    
        quantity = pyautogui.click(998,533)
        submit = pyautogui.click(754,577)
        time.sleep(1)
        confirm = pyautogui.click(757,487)
        pyautogui.click(778,245)
```

for give seconds for the next step

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).